# Select a module using importlib and use in multiprocessing functions

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-import

I'd like to select in my main function which module to import based on an argument passed to the Python script.  So, I'm using one of

```
blah = importlib.import_module("blah1")
blah = importlib.import_module("blah2")
```

where the 'blahX' are different implementations of the same interface.

I also want to pass the work off to different processes using the `multiprocessing` module.

```
blah = None

def f(a, b):
    print blah.f(a,b)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # call importlib.import_module here...

    a = 1
    b = 2
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(a, b))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

The problem is that the functions passed to `multiprocessing.Process` aren't aware of the module I imported in main.  This is different than if I use `import`

```
import blah1 as blah
#import blah2 as blah
```

but then I loose the ability to choose a module at run-time.

How can I fix this design?

Comment: `blah = __import__('blah#')` ?

Comment: I did try `__import__`, but it seems to behave like importlib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `mp.Process(...)`, the multiprocessing module forks a subprocess (on Unix) or starts a new Python process and imports the calling module (on Windows). On Unix your current code would work because all globals at the time of the fork are copied by the new subprocess.

On Windows, however, the calling module is imported. Since the definition of blah, e.g.,

```
blah = importlib.import_module("math")
```

is protected inside

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

the new definition of `blah` does not transfer to the subprocess.

So to make it work with Windows, you could pass the name of the module to the target function, and call `importlib.import_module` there:

```
import importlib
import multiprocessing as mp
blah = None

def f(a, b, name):
    blah = importlib.import_module(name)
    print blah.hypot(a,b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 1
    b = 2
    p = mp.Process(target=f, args=(a, b, "math"))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Thanks. And you're right, I was testing on Windows.  Could the imported module 'blah' object be passed as an argument instead or does the import need to happen inside the target function?

Comment: On Windows, all objects passed to `Process.__init__` [must be picklable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows). Here is a [list of Python objects that are picklable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). Since modules are not picklable, you can not pass the module itself.