# Python multiprocess with importlib modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pickle, python-importlib

Good day to you,
Today I was moving code from `threading` to `multiprocess`. Everything seemed okay, until I got The following error:

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "run.py", line 82, in main
    emenu.executemenu(components, _path)
  File "/home/s1810979/paellego/lib/execute/execute_menu.py", line 29, in executemenu
    e.executeall(installed, _path)
  File "/home/s1810979/paellego/lib/execute/execute.py", line 153, in executeall
    pool.starmap(phase2, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 385, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'module'>: attribute lookup module on builtins failed
```

---

## Code

execute.py

```py
def executeall(components, _path):
    args = []
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()

    resultloc = '/some/result.log'
    for component in components:
        for apkpath, resultpath in zip(execonfig.apkpaths, execonfig.resultpaths):
            args.append((component,apkpath,resultpath,q,)) #Args for subprocesses
    cores = askcores()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cores) as pool:
        watcher = pool.apply_async(lgr.log, (resultloc+'/results.txt', q,))

        pool.starmap(phase2, args)
```

component.py

```py
class Component(object):
    def __init__(self, installmodule, runmodule, installerloc, installationloc, dependencyloc):
        self.installmodule = installmodule
        self.runmodule = runmodule
        self.installerloc = installerloc
        self.installationloc = installationloc
        self.dependencyloc = dependencyloc
        self.config = icnf.Installconfiguration(installerloc+'/conf.conf')
    #lots of functions...
```

installconfig.py

```
class State(Enum):
    BEGIN=0 #Look for units
    UNIT=1  #Look for unit keypairs
    KEYPAIR=3

class Phase(Enum):
    NONE=0
    DEPS=1
    PKGS=2

class Installconfiguration(object):
    def __init__(self, config):
        dictionary = self.reader(config) #Fill a dictionary
        #dictionary (key:Phase, value: (dictionary key: str, job))
        self.deps = dictionary[Phase.DEPS]
        self.pkgs = dictionary[Phase.PKGS]
```

job.py

```
class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, directory=None, url=None):
        self.directory = directory if directory else ''
        self.url = url if url else ''
```

As you can see, I pass a component as argument to `function phase2(component, str, str, multiprocess.manager.Queue())`.

The second and third argument of the constructor of `component` are modules imported with `importlib`.

---

## What I tried

I am new to python, but not to programming. Here is what I tried:

- Because the error itself did not point out what the problem was exactly, I tried removing args to find out which can't be pickled: Remove `component`, and everything works fine, so this appears to be the cause for trouble. However, I need this object passed to my processes.
- I searched around the internet for hours, but did not find anything but basic tutorials about multiprocessing, and explanations about how pickle works. I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503909/select-a-module-using-importlib-and-use-in-multiprocessing-functions) saying it should work, but not on windows or something. However, it does not work on Unix (which I use)

#### My ideas

As I understood it, nothing suggests I cannot send a class containing two importlib modules. I do not know what the exact problem is with `component` class, but importlib module as members are the only non-regular things. This is why I believe the problem occurs here.

---

## Question

Do you know why a class containing modules is unsuitable for 'pickling'? How can one get a better idea why and where `Can't pickle <class 'module'>` errors occur?

#### More code

Full source code for this can be found on https://github.com/Sebastiaan-Alvarez-Rodriguez/paellego

#### Questions to me

Please leave comments requesting clarifications/more code snippets/??? if you would like me to edit this question

#### A last request

I would like solutions to use python standard library only, python 3.3 preferably. Also, a requirement of my code is that it runs on Unix systems.

Thanks in advance

---

## Edit

As requested, here is a minimal example which greatly simplifies the problem:
main.py (you could execute as python main.py foo)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import importlib
import multiprocessing
class clazz(object):
    def __init__(self, moduly):
        self.moduly = moduly

    def foopass(self, stringy):
        self.moduly.foo(stringy)

    def barpass(self, stringy, numbery):
        self.moduly.bar(stringy)
        print('Second argument: '+str(numbery))

def worker(clazzy, numbery):
    clazzy.barpass('wow', numbery)

def main():
    clazzy = clazz(importlib.import_module(sys.argv[1]))
    clazzy.foopass('init')

    args = [(clazzy, 2,)]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        pool.starmap(worker, args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

foo.py (needs to be in same directory for above call suggestion):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
globaly = 0

def foo(stringy):
    print('foo '+stringy)
    global globaly
    globaly = 5

def bar(stringy):
    print('bar '+stringy)
    print(str(globaly))
```

This gives error upon running: `TypeError: can't pickle module objects`
Now we know that pickling module objects is (sadly) not possible.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled

Comment: @Goyo I have seen these docs too. Did you notice that `classes defined at top of module` can be pickled?  Since I import ```component``` at top level of module, it should be possible to pickle it right?

Comment: Not if its attributes have unpicklable values, like seems to be the case here.

Comment: I was thinking this too. The error is about ```<class 'module'>``` though, not about ```<class 'component'>```. Also, do you have any references as to why an importlib module cannot be pickled? Lastly, do you have any ideas about how I still could send ```component ``` to mp processes?

Comment: I think the error is related to `component` having modules as attributes and I don't think it is related to `importlib`. I can't go beyond that without a [mcve] that I can debug. You can rewrite `Component` so that instances don't have modules as attributes.

Comment: Why do you want to store modules as attributes, anyway?

Comment: @DavisHerring My tool is a framework to install things. An installmodule implements a set of functions, e.g. 'preinstall(), install()', which get called during installation process. All user input should be asked on ```preinstall()``` so ```install()``` of multiple components can be done in parallel. Right now, all user input gets stored in globals in the installmodule (so that preinstall() and install() can exchange variables). So that's why I use importlib to store modules as attributes: If I stop doing that, I lose variable communication between functions within components

Comment: @Goyo There is the difficult thing: If I do not store the modules as attributes, I must transform component object to have 1 ```install()``` function. preinstall() and install() would no longer be separated, and I cannot parallelize ```install()``` function. Only if I can receive and send an arbitrary long amount of variables, I can maintain state myself, and then I do not need importlib attributes any longer I think... Maybe if I write everything to a temp file and read it back in later...

Comment: @SebastiaanAlvarezRodriguez: Module attributes are *called* “global variables” in Python, but they are no more persistent or accessible than any other data.  Why not just use dictionaries?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I you need to pass or store some state just do it, you do not need to store modules as attributes for that. Again, this is very confusing without a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get rid of the error, let `clazz` not take a module as attribute, however convenient, but let it take "`modpath`", which is the required string for `importlib` to import the module specified by user.
It looks like this (foo.py remains exactly the same as above):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import importlib
import multiprocessing
class clazz(object):
    def __init__(self, modpathy):
        self.modpathy = modpathy

    def foopass(self, stringy):
        moduly = importlib.import_module(self.modpathy)
        moduly.foo(stringy)

    def barpass(self, stringy, numbery):
        moduly = importlib.import_module(self.modpathy)
        moduly.bar(stringy)
        print('Second argument: '+str(numbery))

def worker(clazzy, number):
    clazzy.barpass('wow', number)

def main():
    clazzy = clazz(sys.argv[1])
    clazzy.foopass('init')

    args = [(clazzy, 2,)]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        pool.starmap(worker, args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you require that your globals, such as `globaly`, are guaranteed to maintain state, then you need to pass a mutable object (e.g. list, dictionary) to hold this data, thanks @DavisHerring:

> Module attributes are called “global variables” in Python, but they are no more persistent or accessible than any other data. Why not just use dictionaries?

The example code would look like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import importlib
import multiprocessing
class clazz(object):
    def __init__(self, modpathy):
        self.modpathy = modpathy
        self.dictionary = {}

    def foopass(self, stringy):
        moduly = importlib.import_module(self.modpathy)
        moduly.foo(stringy, self.dictionary)

    def barpass(self, stringy, numbery):
        moduly = importlib.import_module(self.modpathy)
        moduly.bar(stringy, self.dictionary)
        print('Second argument: '+str(numbery))

def worker(clazzy, number):
    clazzy.barpass('wow', number)

def main():
    clazzy = clazz(sys.argv[1])
    clazzy.foopass('init')

    args = [(clazzy, 2,)]
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        pool.starmap(worker, args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

foo.py (no more globals):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

def foo(stringy, dictionary):
    print('foo '+stringy)
    globaly = 5
    dictionary['globaly'] = globaly

def bar(stringy, dictionary):
    print('bar '+stringy)
    globaly = dictionary['globaly']
    print(str(globaly))
```

This way you can work around the problem without annoying `can't pickle ...` errors, and while maintaining states